# PHP with Sql with Wammp

Tags: php, mysql

`

```
$host="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="project";
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$pass,$dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Connection Failed! :" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];       
    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows>0){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            header("Location: nlogin.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
            }else{
                ?>
                <h1 style="color:white">Username/password is incorrect.</h1>
                <?php
                }
    }
?>`
```

Here I have to make it to connect to Login Page and match password in database
    but it always go to else block "Incorrect Password"

Comment: Are your stored passwords hashed? Are you aware of what sql injection is?

Comment: var_dump($rows) to see what is inside it before the conditions. May be you don't have any user with that username and password or your password is hashed that why your SQL query fails to get any result from db

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.